# SML: difference between type and datatype

Tags: types, sml, smlnj

I'm pretty new at SML and I would like to make sure I really know the basics. What is the difference between type and datatype in SML, and when to use which?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`type` declarations just give another name to an existing type. Declaring `type t = int * int` simply means that you can now write `t` instead of `int * int` - it doesn't actually provide any functionality.

`datatype` definitions let you create brand new types by introducing new *data constructors*. Data constructors are the keywords and symbols you use to create and pattern-match values, such as the list type's `nil` and `::`. There's nothing particularly special about those identifiers; you can define them yourself as easily as this:

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

Comment: One nit: `nil` and `::` are _data_ constructors. A type constructor is a _type_ with parameters, e.g. `list` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Datatypes in sml can have more than one type, e.g.

```
datatype a = SomeType | SomeOtherType
```

You can use them when type-checking, e.g.

```
fun doThings (var : a) : bool =
    case var of
       (SomeType) => true
       (SomeOtherType) => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You may think of it as this: types are for opaque and atomic types, while `datatype` are for type with constructors, and so, which can be destructured, mainly within pattern matching on expressions.

A `datatype` may expose a simple type view too, if it implements an opaque type (declared with `type` in a signature and defined as a `datatype` in a structure implementing the signature).

Atomic type like `int` and `word` may be seen as destructurable types in some respect, like with Peano arithmetic interpretation of numbers, but SML's `int`, `word` and the not so well called `real`, are primitive types.